# Using map in java

Tags: java, sorting, input, arraylist, hashmap

I am working on this app that reads a set of `int`s from the console and then creates a map for each unique `int`. It then counts how many times that input occurs and prints out an ordered tally. This is what I have gotten so far and am having a hard time moving forward from here.

```
package examPrep;

import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.Iterator;

public class mapThatReadsInts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is based on the problem she gave in class

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please Enter a Integer");
        int inputValue = input.nextInt();

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> numberMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        numberMap.put(inputValue, inputValue);

        System.out.println("Size of map " + numberMap.size());
    }
}
```

I know that I have to use an ArrayList here somewhere and also a for loop to iterate over each input. I am just having a hard time figuring out how to do that. Any sort of help would be appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this is homework so I don't want to be too detailed...

1. Presumably this will be in a loop somehow, where the user can enter many integers.  You want to create ("new") the HashMap outside of that loop, not inside where it seems to be now.  Otherwise it will only hold the most recent integer.
2. Within that loop, if the integer is already in the HashMap, you need to handle that differently than if it is the first time entered.  Think about that.
3. Since you want to print them out in order, use a TreeMap instead which keeps them in sorted order.

Hope this gets you started a bit more along the right path...